# How to nest choices with django models, so that it reflects properly in django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Here is my models.py

```
class BrandSection(models.Model):
    """
    Model for storing page's section details
    """
    brand_choices = (
        ('brand1', 'Brand1'),
        ('brand1', 'Brand2'),
        ('brand1', 'Brand3')
    )
    page_choices = (
        ('Brand Page', 'Brand Page'),
        ('PRODUCT_LIST', 'Product List'),
        ('PRODUCT_DETAILS', 'Product Details')
        ....
        ....
        ....
    )
    brand_name = models.CharField(choices=brand_choices, max_length=255, default='brand1')
    page_name = models.CharField(choices=page_choices, max_length=255, default='Brand Page')
```

Now, in django admin panel, user can select the brand name and page name separately. What I want is that page_choices should differ depending on brand_choices. For example, if a person selects brand1 then page_choices should appear different and when he selects brand2 then page_choices should be different.
Any leads will help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to do that dynamically in javascript/JQuery in a [custom admin template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).